# Issue with the Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, ado.net, oracle11g

I have written the below stored procedure to retrieve the data to send to my C# application's DataSet.

Could you please suggest a more robust design for my stored procedure? I'm assuming that this is not the best way to return a record set.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEE_DATA 
(
  EMPLOYEE_EMAIL IN VARCHAR2,
  EMP_RECORD_SET1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  EMP_RECORD_SET2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  EMP_RECORD_SET3 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  EMP_RECORD_SET4 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN
  OPEN EMP_RECORD_SET1 FOR

  SELECT EMPLOYEENAME AS EMP_NAME,
         EMPLOYEELASTNAME AS EMP_LAST_NAME,
         EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME AS EMP_FIRST_NAME
         FROM EMP.EMPLOYEES
         WHERE EMP_EMAIL = EMPLOYEE_EMAIL
      ;

     OPEN EMP_RECORD_SET2 FOR 


        SELECT EMPLOYEEADD AS EMP_ADDRESSESS,
         EMPLOYEECITY AS EMP_CITY,
         EMPLOYEE_STATE AS EMP_STATE
         FROM EMP.EMPLOYEES_ADDRESSES
         WHERE EMP_EMAIL = EMPLOYEE_EMAIL;

      OPEN EMP_RECORD_SET3 FOR

        SELECT EMPLOYEEPHONE AS EMP_PHONE,
         EMPLOYEEEXTENSION AS EMP_EXTENSION
         FROM EMP.EMPLOYEES_CONTACTS
         WHERE EMP_EMAIL = EMPLOYEE_EMAIL
      ;

      OPEN EMP_RECORD_SET4 FOR

  SELECT EMPLOYEEJOB AS EMP_JOB,
         EMPLOYEERESPONSIBILITIES AS EMP_RESPONSIBILITIES
         FROM EMP.EMPLOYEES_DATA
         WHERE EMP_EMAIL = EMPLOYEE_EMAIL
      ;


END GET_PROTOCOL_INFO_SP;
```

I need to know whether my syntax is correct and whether I should close the cursors. I have 4 different table where the data is called in the app.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What are you doing with these results in your client application?  Are you really presenting 4 completely independent tables of results?  Or are you presenting a single view of different attributes of an employee?  Is `EMP_EMAIL` a key in any of these tables?  Or is it really possible for there to be many rows in all 4 tables with the same `EMPLOYEE_EMAIL`?  If there are multiple employees with the same email, how do you determine in the client which address/ phone/ etc. data goes with which employee?

Comment: thanks marc_s. @justin cave - i need to know whether my syntax are correct and whether i should closed the cursors. yes i have 4 different table where the data is called in the app

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a reasonable enough SP, if you want to get 4 different datatables.
You may also consider retrieving only one, joined, datatable, depending on the amount of expected rows per employee and your application's needs.

In any case, you may want to use more meaningful names for your datatables (such as `Employees_Phones`, `Employees_Addresses` etc.)

Comment: Quick question , would there me a limit for SYS_REFCURSOR ? How do i close the cursors here if needed? please edit my code to sample out.

Answer (score 0):

- Your syntax appears to be valid.
- You cannot close the cursors in the stored procedure.  Since the cursors are being returned to the client, the client application is responsible for closing them.  Assuming the client is a C# application based on the tag, the C# application will need to close the cursor.

Architecturally, it is unusual to design a stored procedure that returns 4 separate `SYS_REFCURSOR` parameters particularly where most of the queries would seem to return either 1 row of data (assuming `EMP_EMAIL` is a key in the `EMPLOYEES` table) or a handful of rows of data (if, for example, employees may have multiple addresses).  If `EMP_EMAIL` is not a key in the `EMPLOYEES` table, I don't see any way for the client to figure out which address, which phone number, or which job goes with which employee which would almost certainly be a bug.  It would be much more common to return a single `SYS_REFCURSOR` that resulted from joining the four tables in the database together if there are going to be many rows returned, to return scalars (potentially scalar types) if you know that only one row should be returned, or to have four separate procedures if you really want four independent result sets returned.  Personally, I'd prefer to return collections rather than a `SYS_REFCURSOR` if you really want addresses in a separate `OUT` parameter from phone numbers but that may be harder to map to your C# application assuming your C# application is really declaring four separate GUI controls to display the four separate result sets.

As a general convention, I would strongly suggest using some sort of naming convention to identify parameters and to separate them from column names and potential column names.  And I would suggest using anchored types.  I would personally use a `P_` prefix, something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEE_DATA 
(
  P_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL IN EMP.EMPLOYEES.EMAIL%TYPE,
  P_EMP_RECORD_SET1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  P_EMP_RECORD_SET2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  P_EMP_RECORD_SET3 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  P_EMP_RECORD_SET4 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
```

The reason for this naming convention is that when you're writing a SQL statement in a PL/SQL block, identifiers are resolved first using the name of a column and then using a local variable.  That leads lots of people to inadvertently write code where they intend to compare a local variable to a column name but end up comparing a column name to itself.  For example, if I write something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_employee (
  emp_email  IN emp.employees.email%type,
  rc        OUT sys_refcursor 
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN rc
   FOR select *
         from emp.employees e
        where e.emp_email = emp_email;
END;
```

it is clear that my intention is to compare the `emp_email` from the `employees` table against the `emp_email` parameter.  Instead, however, this code ends up comparing the `emp_email` from the `employees` table against itself and returns every row from the table where `emp_email` is not NULL.  If, instead, I use a consistent naming convention for parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_employee (
  p_emp_email  IN emp.employees.email%type,
  p_rc        OUT sys_refcursor 
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_rc
   FOR select *
         from emp.employees e
        where e.emp_email = p_emp_email;
END;
```

then it is immediately much clearer if I am inadvertently referring to a column name when I intend to refer to a local variable or vice versa.

In general, I would also strongly suggest that every procedure be a part of a package.  That helps with organization, allowing you to group related procedures together.  In this case, this organization would be helpful if you decided to break this procedure up into four separate procedures each of which returned a single `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  Packages allow you to define private methods that are only available to methods in the package which helps with encapsulation.  And packages help with dependency management since other packages only need to be recompiled when you change the package specification rather than the package body.